# Backbone.js: trouble apending ouput to div

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, append

I need to know how to adapt the following tutorial so that instead of writing the output from a view to `document.body`, I am writing it to a specific `div` with id `#listings`.  See the tutorial I am adapting code from here and scroll to the last long block of code:
http://www.codebeerstartups.com/2012/12/11-namespacing-in-backbone-js-learning-backbonejs/

If you scroll to the bottom, you will see:

```
$(document.body).append(peopleView.render().el);
```

Instead, I want something like:

```
$(document.body.div#listings).append(peopleView.render().el);
```

Anyone know how to do this? I am new to backbone. Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: I think this has something to do with defining an el but I don't know...

Answer (score 5):

this syntax is wrong

```
$(document.body.div#listings).append(peopleView.render().el);
```

you can select `#listings` this way

```
$(document.body).find("div#listings").append(peopleView.render().el);
```

it will select your document body and then it will find the `div` with id `listings`

or Just use

```
$("div#listings").append(peopleView.render().el);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse. You can do with ease.

Suppose you have a div with id "listings" use this:
`$('#listings').append(peopleView.render().el);`